# Set color for status buttons inside grid

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, buttons, grid, status

I have to update the buttons for a grid. Currently the ones used are the ones in the skin/light orange color and I am testing different ones.

There are 4 buttons:

- Active
- Inactive
- Active long term
- Inactive long term

[image]

The idea I like most is on the bottom right. Looks more simple and clear, but it is not very obvious when a button is for a long term or not (bold minus or green tick), so my manager is suggesting the top left option, which for me, is a bit too much colorful and harder to see in a fast view.

What would you recommend me to do? Which option will be easier to read for the user?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For more consistent design you could try this way.
[image]
Still, as semantics behind graphics could be misinterpeted, you should support users with tooltops or/and legend.